# 3 Pointers in 1 Function - Calculator doesn´t work

Tags: c, pointers, while-loop, switch-statement, function-pointers

I've a problem with a function in my calculator-program. The function returns me back only 0 values​​. I want that:

```
Input:3+4
Output:7
```

I have worked with pointers to use the call by reference method. Please give me some tips.
The mistake is in the function `readcalc`. If I write the whole syntax in the main program it works.

Here is my code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
double readcalc(double*,char*,double*);
double addition(double,double);
double subtraction(double,double);
double multiplication(double,double);
double division(double,double);

int main()
{
  double a=0, b=0;
  char op='R', restart = 'Y';
  while (restart != 'N')
  {
    readcalc(&a,&op,&b);
    printf("%lf%lf", a, b);
    printf("\n ---CALCULATOR--- \n\n\n");
    switch (op)
    {

    case '+':printf("%lf + %lf = %lf\n", a, b, addition(a, b)); break;
    case '-':printf("%lf - %lf = %lf\n", a, b, subtraction(a, b)); break;
    case '*':printf("%lf * %lf = %lf\n", a, b, multiplication(a, b)); break;
    case '/':printf("%lf / %lf = %lf\n", a, b, division(a, b)); break;
    default:printf("bad operator!");
    }
    printf("New Calc? (Y,N) \n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c", &restart);
    if (restart != 'Y'&&restart != 'N')
    {
        printf("Bad input!");
    }
  } 
  fflush(stdin);
  getchar();
  return 0;
}

double readcalc(double* x,char* opp,double* y)
{

  printf("\n Type your calculation!(z.B.4+7)\n");
  scanf("%lf%c%lf", &x, &opp, &y);
  return 0;

}

double addition(double a,double b)
{
  double c = 0;
  c = a + b;
  return c;
}

double subtraction(double a, double b)
{
  double c = 0;
  c = a - b;
  return c;
}

double multiplication(double a, double b)
{
  double c = 0;
  c = a*b;
  return c;
}

double division(double a, double b)
{
  double c = 0;
  c = a / b;
  return c;
}
```

What can I change?

Comment: Welcome on SO. The readability of your program would be better with some indentation. I t would be good to show us why you think the problem is in `readcalc()` to help us find the problem

Comment: "z.B." does not mean "for example" in English. :) You should use "e.g.".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with `readcalc` is that you pass the pointer to the pointer as argument to `scanf`. The variables are already pointers, so you don't have to use the address-of operator to get a pointer, as then you get pointers to the pointers.

Also be careful with the `scanf` format, as the `"%c"` format doesn't skip leading whitespace, so if you enter e.g. `1 +2` then the `scanf` call will not be able to read the operator or the second number.

Answer (score 3):

```
void readcalc(double* x,char* opp,double* y)
{

    printf("\n Type your calculation!(z.B.4+7)\n");
    scanf("%lf%c%lf", x, opp, y); // <== no &'s

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `readcalc` function invokes

```
scanf("%lf%c%lf", &x, &opp, &y);
```

on pointers, `int *x`, etc...

When you place it inline in main, it works on the addresses of the variables.
Change it to

```
scanf("%lf%c%lf", x, opp, y);
```

At a suitable warning level, you may have seen warning.

While you are there, `readcalc` returns a double, which you never use. Perhaps it should simply be void?